# nodejs loop function calls output problm

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops

I have a question I don't understand how this code works.

```
ans.map((val, indx) => {
   const options = {
        host: 'www.xxxx.com',
        path: '/path'
        port: 80,
        path: path,
        method: 'GET',
    };

    console.log(val)

    send.getJSON(options, (code ,result) => {
        console.log("oke22");
    });
})
```

For `[1,2,3]`, the output I get is:

```
1
2
3
oke
oke
oke
```

Why is the output not the following instead?

```
1
oke
2
oke
3
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your `.getJSON` is asynchronous, running in synchronous code, this isn't bad, however it's handled slightly differently.

The design of Node.js uses an event-loop to provide asynchronicity on a single-threaded language like JavaScript.

So your callback won't actually be called until the `.getJSON()` has completed.

https://jsfiddle.net/uva5o10d/

Have a look here, I've made you an example to demonstrate what I mean, I simply fill an array with values (all 1s for this example), and set a callback function up using setTimeout (this delays by 1s), notice however, the program will continue to run. (Event-loop)

At the bottom of the file, notice the `test()`, this calls the version you currently have (very similar), including the call to a longer-running job, like retrieving data from an API.

Comment out `test()` and uncomment `working()` and you'll see the different, you may want to use `console.log(value + " " + oke)` inside your `.getJSON`, producing the results you're looking for.

- https://codeforgeek.com/asynchronous-programming-in-node-js/

Also side-note, `forEach` would probably be a better method for iterating over an array, unless you're wanted a transformed array back (`map`).

I've attached some resources I think you may find helpful:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array
- https://www.techopedia.com/definition/3821/iteration (you're already on track but always worth having a read if you're not overly familiar).